# Getting a Node::SharedPtr from "this"

Tags: ros2, c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A number of functions expect a `rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr`, but when you are in an `rclcpp::Node` subclass it is not available, and of course something like `foo(rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr(this));` is a great way to crash your program. Is there some registry of these `SharedPtr`s to query?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353828/getting-a-node::sharedptr-from-%22this%22/) by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2020-06-02

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[`rclcpp::Node` inherits from `std::enable_shared_from_this<>`](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/bf70ce15bf5e80a083b59bce39fa860ac47f4a8f/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/node.hpp#L72). You can get a shared pointer to a node by calling `shared_from_this()` in your subclass. There's more info about [`std::enable_shared_from_this<>` here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this).

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2020-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on 2020-06-08**:
An important caveat is you can't call `shared_from_this` in your class's constructor because the object doesn't yet fully exist to make a `shared_ptr` from. There you can only use APIs that use either a raw pointer or individual node interfaces.

**Comment by [swiz23](https://answers.ros.org/users/52899/swiz23/) on 2023-03-06**:
I realize this thread is old, but what is the reason you can still do `this->create_publisher<std_msgs::msg::String>("topic", 10);` in the constructor? Wouldn't the same reason - that the object doesn't fully exist yet - still apply?

**Comment by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on 2023-03-13**:
@swiz23 Looks like I phrased it badly. The object does exist from the time the constructor body starts since initialization is completed at that point. But `shared_from_this` requires a `shared_ptr` to already be managing the object and that won't be created until after the constructor returns (assuming you're using something like `make_shared`).