# Using ImageTransport in a constructor throws std::bad_weak_ptr

Tags: ros2, node, image-transport, rclcpp

I am trying to create an `ImageTransport` instance to set up an image publisher which is a class member).
I stick to [this](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_transport_tutorials) example, trying to adapt it to my class:

```
image_transport::ImageTransport it(this->shared_from_this());
my_pub_ = it.advertise("camera/image", 1);
```

The first line throws an instance of 'std::bad_weak_ptr'.
This behaviour is also explained [here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/96027/getting-a-nodesharedptr-from-this): I cannot use shared_from_this within a constructor.

What can I do instead? There must be some ROS2 way to instantiate objects that require a shared node in their constructor?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are ways around this, e.g., having an initialize method that is called externally or using a timer that calls an initialize method (very hacky and prone to hard to find bugs, don't do this).

However, the general issue you have here is not that you can't pass the shared ptr of your Node-derived class to `image_transport` but that you should not.
If your class stores an instance of `ImageTransport` (which it would probably also implicitly if you store the created `Publisher`), it will hold an instance to the `shared_ptr` of your class which means you have a cycle in your smart pointer graph and this memory is leaked as the instance counter can never reduce to 0.
In other words, your class is indirectly holding a `shared_ptr` of itself.

A possible alternative would be to have your class not inherit from node but instead create a node as a member which you can then also pass to the `ImageTransport` constructor.